# Vue / Laravel - Importing CDN vuetify instead of npm install

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

Since I wanted to reduce my `app.js` file size, will it be possible to import a CDN/UNPKG vuetify inside my `app.js`? Will the load time be the same if I import it locally (`npm install`) and through cdn?

I managed to reduce it by using the cdn for css, icons and fonts but not for the whole package.

I tried this method and it doesn't work.

**Welcome.blade.php**

```
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
            <app id="app"></app>
    </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

**App.js**

```
window.Vue = require('vue')

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import 'vue-nprogress'

import App from '@/App.vue'
import routes from '@/routes.js'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

Vue.component('base-table', () => import('@/components/BaseTable.vue'));

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h=>h(App),
  vuetify: new Vuetify({
    theme: {
      themes: {
        light: {
          primary: '#1565C0',
          secondary: '#b0bec5',
          accent: '#8c9eff',
          error: '#b71c1c',
        },
      },
    },
  }),
  router: new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes,
  })
});
```

Comment: You'll need to tell webpack (or other bundler) you are providing Vuetify externally. Here's how I've done it for React and ReactDOM, for example: https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/blob/c254df931c4e913973a7d603cf5a3443106d2c66/client/webpack/prod.config.js?ts=2#L27-L50

Comment: If you get it via CDN (in the standard way) you can't use `import` on it since it's not actually a local module. You can still access it via the `window` object if it actually adds itself there

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm having an idea now. I used this syntax .webpackConfig({
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/')
        }
      },
      externals: {
        "vuetify": "Vuetify",
     },

and I was able to reduce the size but it's not displaying so I might need a few more steps.

Comment: @apokryfos Yeah you're right. I'm now trying to do what jonshapre have said, I still need a few more steps but I'm getting there.

Comment: I was able to make it work right now. I'll post the answer. Thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 3):

I moved my Vue, VueRouter and Vuetify externally. From 1.74 MB, down to 57.5 kb. That's a huge improvement for my app.js file.

[image]

Thank you very much to **@jonrsharpe** and **@apokryfos**

**Webpack.mix.js**

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .webpackConfig({
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/')
        }
      },
      externals: {
        'lodash':'_',
        'vue':'Vue',
        "vuetify": "Vuetify",
        "vue-router": "VueRouter",
     },
    });
```

**Welcome.blade.php**

```html
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
            <app id="app"></app>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@3.1.3/dist/vue-router.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

App.js remains the same